# Stencil - Global CSS Doesn't Integrate into React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stenciljs, stencil-component

Following the Stencil docs [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling), I created some global CSS variables in src/global/variables.css. This is currently the only CSS file in this directory.

I’m trying to use my component(s) in React. The components / CSS variables work perfectly fine when developing in the Stencil project and when I copy the www/build/ directory to a vanilla JS / HTML project but not when I import and use them in React. The components work and clearly render but the CSS in the global/ directory clearly doesn’t get rendered.

Defining and using CSS variables within the component CSS files works, but not the global CSS files.

I’m guessing something is wrong with how I’m building it but I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

I've tried updating to the most recent Stencil version and updated all other packages.

I've also tried adding:

```
styleUrls: [
    "local-component.css",
    "../../global/variables.css"
]
```

but this also did not work.

It only works if add a CSS  tag referencing the UNPKG CDN like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/uwe-ds-poc@0.0.9/dist/poc/poc.css"/>`

but fails if I try to do a local path like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/uwe-ds-poc/dist/poc/poc.css"/>`.

Is this the only / best approach or is there something I am missing?

This is my stencil.config.ts:

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'poc',
  globalStyle: 'src/global/variables.css',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: 'loader'
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme'
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null // disable service workers
    }
  ],
  copy: [
    { src: 'global' }
  ]
};
```

The copy property copies the global dir across to dist/collection/.  This doesn't resolve the problem either.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "uwe-ds-poc",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "description": "Stencil Component Starter",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "es2015": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "es2017": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "collection": "dist/collection/collection-manifest.json",
  "collection:main": "dist/collection/index.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/poc/poc.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "loader/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "stencil build --docs",
    "start": "stencil build --dev --watch --serve",
    "test": "stencil test --spec --e2e",
    "test.watch": "stencil test --spec --e2e --watchAll",
    "generate": "stencil generate"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stencil/core": "^1.8.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/puppeteer": "1.20.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.8.0",
    "puppeteer": "1.20.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

This entire Stencil project is [here](https://gitlab.uwe.ac.uk/computing-project/stencil-poc/tree/master/poc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the unpkg cdn is a valid option.

However if you are using a bundler (webpack, parcel, etc.) you could just import your css with something like `import 'my-package/dist/path/to/global.css'`.